# Occasionally need to restart WiFi interface on wake

Tags: networking, wireless, suspend, dhcp, restart

For some reason, after restarting my computer my WiFi works fine, and the interface is always up. However, when I wake up my computer from sleep, the interface connects to WiFi but I can't connect to the internet unless I run `sudo ifdown wlp2s0 && sudo ifup -v wlp2s0`. Does anyone know what might be the cause of this? My `/etc/modules` file has no modules and my `/etc/network/interfaces/` file looks like:

```
# interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8) 
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp

auto wlp2s0
iface wlp2s0 inet dhcp
```

I am currently running Ubuntu 18.04 on a Dell XPS 9650.

Comment: I am shocked that this works *at all* without an SSID nor a WPA2 password declared. Is this a conflict between this file and Network Manager? Netplan is the usual (and not trivial) way to manually control interfaces in 18.04.

Comment: Actually, generating a new netplan seems to have fixed the issue, thank you! I had no conflicts with network manager or any other noticable conflicts, just the occasional failure of the connection.